# Add Access File on SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: microsoft-access

How can I add .accdb file on SharePoint Designer 2013?

I looked blocked file types on Central Administration but I didn't find accdb and I didn't remove from the list.

[image]

When I create new access app I got errors:

> AddAccessApp.ValidateUserHasInstallRights: Validate that the user has app Install permissions 9f81119d-d671-c067-e92a-0d034159d910
>
> AddAccessApp.OpenExistingApp: FileName=KUH_HPB_Dbase_v1.3.accdb; 
>   ContentType=application/octet-stream; Size=11145216.    9f81119d-d671-c067-e92a-0d034159d910
>
> Access Services                 Application Design              allm8   Medium      TemplateManager.InstallAccessPackageAndDoNotWait: Validating the Access .app package    9f81119d-d671-c067-e92a-0d034159d910
>
> AccessPackageBuilder.ValidateAccessPackage: Validating the Access app package.    9f81119d-d671-c067-e92a-0d034159d910
>
> UserProfileDBCache.GetChangedDBItemsPrimaryKeys: m_AllPropertyIDs = 1;3;9;2;5009;7;23;13;14;22;5065;5061;5062;5040;5042;5091;5092;5093;5096;5097;5098;
>
> ccessPackageBuilder.IsValidAccessAppPackage: Validating the Access app package threw an exception: {System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.     at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.FindPosition(Stream archiveStream)     at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.LoadEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock()     at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.OpenOnStream(Stream stream, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)     at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)     at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)     at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Design.AccessPackageBuilder.IsValidAccessAppPackage(Stream appPackageStream)}.  9f81119d-d671-c067-e92a-0d034159d910
>
> AddAccessApp.OpenExistingApp: Unexpected exception thrown while creating the Access app. Message: {System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.     at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.FindPosition(Stream archiveStream)     at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.LoadEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock()

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with that accdb file in SP Designer?

Comment: I want to add accdb file on pages. Then, users will show and edit the file. @ZakirHC

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to add the access file in a SharePoint library. There is a related article on storing Access related files [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2c4106d-22dc-425d-b267-048135ab5587/should-you-store-access-databases-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneral). It describes that even though some access file types are blocked some are allowed(Example .accdb and .accdp) in SP 2013.

I'm using SP 2013 Foundation. Tried manually adding a .accdb in a SP 2013 library.  SharePoint takes some time to add the access database file in to the SP library. I could see the .accdb among the list items, not immediately but after 2 seconds delay. (Note that my .accdb file size is very small, 370 kb). So it seems adding .accdb is not an issue. Could you please check the file size. Not sure whether that's causing any trouble for you.

But if you are trying to manipulate the file using SP Designer, could you explain a bit more on what you are attempting to do

Comment: I updated my questions. When I add access db in access app I got error, I add logs in my questions.

Comment: This situation is due to the file size may be larger?